# How do I add user input to a void function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that asks for a string of text, then adds it to a log file of sorts. In its current form the code prints literally "%s".

```
int main()
{   
    char input[512];
    printf("input string: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    putText("%s", input);
    printf("\ndone!\n");
    
    return 0;
}

void putText(char userText[])
{
    FILE * log;
    log = fopen("log1.txt", "a+"); //a+ for append + create.
    fprintf(log, "%s\n", userText);
    //fclose(log);
        
}
```

Also I'm pretty new to all this, although that's probably pretty obvious from where you all are sitting.

Comment: `putText("%s", input);` -->    `putText(input);`

Comment: Your compiler should be showing you some warnings related to errors in your code. Always heed the compiler warnings.

Comment: `void putText(char userText[])` takes exactly one parameter. But you are passing two.  Are you asking how to make a printf type function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters?

Comment: I was using functions wrong, I thought I had to do it similarly to printf.

Comment: if you stick with `C` you will learn to love `void`.  Check out `Pass by reference` example here: https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass printf-like parameters to your own function, you need to use a function with variadic arguments. Here is a simple example:

```
int putText(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    FILE * log;
    log = fopen("log1.txt", "a+"); //a+ for append + create.
    fprintf(log, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

For the corresponding documentation, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html